# Should I add the sass source map to my git repo?

Tags: css, git, sass

I had added `style.css.map` to my `.gitignore` file thinking that this was some kind of internal file that was not needed for public consumption.

Now I'm seeing that when Chrome (not Firefox) loads my page, it is looking for `style.css.map` and returning a 404. I'm not explicitly asking it to load that file, but it seems to be getting called automatically.

1. Why is Chrome looking for that file?
2. Should I have included the .map file to the repo?

For further context, this is a Wordpress site and I *am* including the `style.scss` file in the repo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Using sourcemaps you can live edit the scss using the devtools.

For each generated CSS file, Sass is generating a source map file (.map file) in addition to the compiled CSS. Each CSS file contains an annotation that specifies the URL of its source map file, embedded in a special comment on the last line of the file:

/*# sourceMappingURL= */

More info about sourcemaps:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors

2. If you want to use sourcemaps on prod, you must have the .map file, if you don't need it, just disable its generation. If you are using grunt to run Sass, check your config.rb file and look for the sass_options entry, you might find ":sourcemap => true", if you find it, set it to false. Beware that sourcemaps are default on Sass 3.4.

Comment: Ah, so it sounds as though pretty much the *only* purpose of the source map is for browser debugging. That's what I'm getting from your answer and the link you pasted. Is that your understanding as well?

Comment: Yeah, it has no effect on the page itself. Rather than seeing the css as a source on dev tools, you see the scss.